# Theme Editor does not show the actual controls being affected by theme

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having a problem with the Theme Editor where, instead of showing a checkbox in the `Checkbox` preview, it just literally displays the word "checkbox". This also occurs in the `App bar`, `ProgressBar` (indeterminate and horizontal), `SeekBar`, and `Radiobutton` previews.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/SpecialRed</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondaryText</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

[image: Screenshot of Theme Editor]

Comment: Can you show the style XML you are using?

Comment: @cricket_007 updated

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I can't reproduce the problem. I am previewing with API 23, though

Comment: @cricket_007 I feel like I got my IDE in a bad state, but invalidating caches/restart didn't help. Also, I'm previewing with API 24, however switching to 23 didn't cause anything to change.

Answer (score 0):

go to file in top left of android studio and select invalidate cache and restart .This will fix the issue